# Randomly generate id from database and make sure it isn't repeated

Tags: c#, sql, database, command, inner-join

I'm trying to randomly generate questions to be answered in a quiz from my question table in a database but I don't want 2 of the same questions in a quiz.

As the question is asked I am putting them into a table using

```
SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tests]( TestID, UserID, Date, QuestionsID) VALUES ('"+1+"','"+ StudentLoginForm.UserInformation.UserID + "',GETDATE(),'" + QuestionID.Questionid + "')", con);
```

with the aim to compare the contents of this table with the questions id to pick a question.

I am using the following select statement to select the questions to be asked but it some times produces the same question

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT QuestionID, Answer, Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD FROM dbo.Questions LEFT JOIN Tests ON Questions.QuestionID = Tests.QuestionsID order by newid()", con);
```

Any help to try and solve this problem would be much appreciated .

Comment: I think the problem is using the newid() with a join.

I think this might be helpful? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aeb83251-e132-435a-8630-e5b842a69368/random-join-between-tables?forum=sqldataaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join is likely producing duplicates, so you'll have to either fix the data, or use a DISTINCT in your query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT QuestionID, Answer, Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD
FROM dbo.Questions 
LEFT JOIN Tests ON Questions.QuestionID = Tests.QuestionsID
```

Comment: If I am to use SELECT DISTINCT within my statement will it not stop the order by newid from working, which is doing the randomisation?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a better solution is to solve your data design problem, why is it returning duplicates in the first place?  Why do you have more than one Test record for each question?